What is the correct way to encode the 2nd projection of a dependent pair type?
Consider the following Church-encoded definition for a dependent pair type (a.k.a. existential type) in a pure type system such as the Calculus of Constructions:
$$\operatorname{Exists} \;\; := \;\; \lambda A:*. \; \lambda F:A\to *. \; \Pi T:*. \; (\Pi x:A. \; F(x)\to T)\to T$$
We can define the constructor as:
$$\operatorname{exists} \;\; := \;\; \lambda A:*. \; \lambda F:A\to *. \; \lambda a:A. \; \lambda b:F(x). \; \lambda T:*. \; \lambda f:(\Pi z:A. \; F(z)\to T). \; f(a, b)$$
While the 1st projection which returns the first element of the pair is straightforward to define:
$$\operatorname{first} \;\; := \;\; \lambda A:*. \; \lambda F:A\to *. \; \lambda p:\operatorname{Exists}(A, F). \; p(A, \;\; \lambda x:A. \; \lambda y:F(x). \; x)$$
the 2nd projection for obtaining the second element of the pair is surprisingly nontrivial.
I found several internet sources claiming the correct encoding is as follows:
$$\operatorname{second} \;\; := \;\; \lambda A:*. \; \lambda F:A\to *. \; \lambda p:\operatorname{Exists}(A, F). \; p(F(\operatorname{first}(p)), \;\; \lambda x:A. \; \lambda y:F(x). \; y)$$
but this definition seems to fail type checking because $p$ expects a second argument of type $\Pi x:A. \; F(x)\to F(\operatorname{first}(p))$ whereas the actual term provided has type $\Pi x:A. \; F(x)\to F(x)$.
While it seems clear in this case that $x=\operatorname{first}(p)$, I don't see how a type checker would be able to infer this using the derivation rules alone, or without sidestepping the problem by normalizing the entire expression before type checking (which seems inefficient as a general strategy).
Is there a better way to define $\operatorname{Exists}$ and/or its 2nd projection that resolves these problems? Is a different type system necessary or am I perhaps overlooking a clever usage of the conversion rule to type check the above definition?
I'm fairly new to the subject and any suggestions for further reading are welcome.

You might want to look through existing Questions and Answers at Proof Assistants SE.  I'm not an expert but it seems very much of a kind with other topics there.

You cannot encode the second projection. The calculus of constructions only encodes weak sums, where you can do case analysis, but the result does not depend on the values. To encode strong sums (which would have a second projection), you need some addition to the theory, like internal parametricity or the dependent intersections of Cedille.
